# copy static array in a dynamic array in c++

Tags: arrays, string, c++17, copy-constructor

The main goal of this code is to copy part of the strings from myArray to neuArray and then output the copied strings from neuArray to the console.
the code is working but not 100% because i get the following report: Access violation while reading at position 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF.

could someone maybe help? thanks in advance

```
string myArray[5];

const int len = (sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]));

myArray[0] = ausgabe; // die ausgabe ist ein binäre string 0101

const int x = 5;
const int y = 1;



string neuArray[x + y] = {};

memcpy(neuArray, myArray, len * (sizeof(string)));

for (int i = 0; i < x + y; i++) {
    cout << neuArray[i] <<endl;}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the code you show is that you use the C function `memcpy`. It will make a shallow byte-wise copy, which doesn't invoke the objects copy-semantics as expected by C++.

That means you will have *undefined behavior* when you try to access the "copied" objects.

You should use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead:

```
std::copy(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), std::begin(neuArray));
```

---

Or stop using fixed-size arrays when you clearly need a dynamic array, and therefore should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: when you can use the function memcpy() in c++ ??

Comment: @Elayoub To be on the safe side: Never. Once you get more experience you will know when it's possible or not.